# The '.onChange' method doesn't get the newest info of 'Input' in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import reqwest from './public/reqwest.js'

const PAGE_SIZE = 10

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      page: 1,
      arr: []
    }
  }

  singleInfo(page) {
    reqwest({
      url: 'https://cnodejs.org/api/v1/topics',
      data: {
        limit: PAGE_SIZE,
        page: this.state.page
      },
      success: function (data) {
        this.setState({
          arr: data.data
        })
      }.bind(this)
    })
  }

  changeState(newState) {
    this.setState(newState)

    this.singleInfo(newState.page)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Menu val={this.state.page} changeParentState={(state) => this.changeState(state)} />
        <List arr={this.state.arr} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Menu extends Component {
  handleChange(event) {
    if(event.target.value) {
      this.props.changeParentState({
        page: event.target.value
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this)
    return <input type="text" defaultValue={this.props.val} onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event)} />
  }
}

class List extends Component {
  render() {
    return <ul>
      {
          this.props.arr.map((ele) => {
            return (
              <li key={ ele.id }>
                <p className="title">{ ele.title }</p>
                <p className="date">{ ele.create_at }</p>
                <p className="author">{ ele.author.loginname }</p>
              </li>
            )
          })
      }
    </ul>
  }
}
```

I can't get the current value of the `input` by `onChange` in `Menu module`.

In my code, the App has two child components - `List` & `Menu`.
You can input the page in `Menu` component, so it will send Ajax() to get the info of the page. But the truth is: After I change the value of input like 1 -> 10, the ajax get the value of 1.

Before this, I know the difference between `keyup` or `keydown` and `keypress`. They have the difference cross browser. But I just **want get the current value of the input By React.js**.

Comment: Could you please set up a working JSBin example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, change:

```
<input type="text" defaultValue={this.props.val} onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event)} />
```

To:

```
<input type="text" value={this.props.val} onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event)} />
```

so that your input will update to the correct value on re-render.

Second, remember that `setState` is often asynchronous.  So do not expect the state to be changed right after calling `setState`.

Your `changeState` method is good in this respect since it passes `newState` to `singlePageRequest`.  However `singlePageRequest` does not use the supplied value and instead uses `this.state.page`.  Change it to use the supplied value and you should be OK:

```
singleInfo(page) {
  reqwest({
    url: 'https://cnodejs.org/api/v1/topics',
    data: {
      limit: PAGE_SIZE,
      page: page
    },
    success: function (data) {
      this.setState({
        arr: data.data
      })
    }.bind(this)
  })
}
```

Comment: `setState` is often asynchronous. I understand. Thanks~